# Class 'Models\Eloquent' not found when trying to namespace my models

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to use namespaces with my models in a Laravel 4 application.

**Models/Fix.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Models; // Namespace Declaration
class Fix extends Eloquent {        
    public static function getFixes() {
        return DB::table('fixes')->get();
    }
}
?>
```

**FixController.php**

```
<?php
class FixController extends BaseController {
    public function showFix() {
        $fixes = Models\Fix::getFixes();  // Referring to Fix Class in Models namespace  
        return View::make('partials.fix', array(
            'fixes' => $fixes,
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

In doing this, I receive the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Models\Fix' not found

$fixes = Models\Fix::getFixes();
```

Following https://coderwall.com/p/nhwq8w I used `composer dump-auto` from terminal window and tried re-running... To find the following error.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Models\Eloquent' not found

class Fix extends Eloquent {
```

Comment: Just a little question back: In which namespace is the class `Eloquent`?

Comment: I have no idea... I was following instructions in http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-learnings-week-2/ however thanks for the little hint... Lead to me finding the solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution - Need to add use statements into each of the models...

```
<?php 
namespace Models;
use Eloquent; // ******** This Line *********
use DB;       // ******** This Line *********
class Fix extends Eloquent {
    public static function getFixes() {
        return DB::table('fixes')->get();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Or prefix with `\` like `class Fix extends \Eloquent`.